# I need to read input data from the keyboard without hitting enter in RStudio

Tags: r, input

I'm programming the classic ping pong atari game in R and I'm having a minor setback concerning the movement of the paddles. I'm trying to read input from the keyboard so the users can move the paddles but I need to read it "quickly" and by quickly I mean without hitting the enter button using the scan() function for example. Also, I need the program to continue running if the user doesn't move the paddles, but I imagine I can do that with a simple if with a clock-ish condition. Any advise on this will be greatly appreciated. I leave my code pingpong code so far:

```
sale = FALSE
x.dir <- runif(1,min=-1,max=1)
y.dir <- runif(1,min=-1,max=1)
x<-0
y<-0
barra.izq<-c(-1,1)
barra.der<-c(-1,1)
while (sale==FALSE){
  plot.new()
  plot.window(xlim=c(-6,6),y=c(-6,6))
  rect(-5.,-5.,5.,5., angle=45)    #rectangulo de cancha
  rect(-5.1,barra.izq[1],-5,barra.izq[2], col="blue")   #barra izquierda
  rect(5.,barra.der[1],5.1,barra.der[2], col="blue")   #barra derecha
  points(x,y)
  x<-x+(x.dir)/3
  y<-y+(y.dir)/3
  if (abs(x)>=5) {
        if (x<0){
          if((barra.izq[1] < y) && (y < barra.izq[2])){
          x.dir <- - x.dir
          }
          else {
          sale <- TRUE
          points(x,y,col= "red")
          }
      }
      if (x>0){
          if( (barra.der[1]<y) && (y < barra.der[2])){
          x.dir <- -x.dir 
          }
          else {
          sale <- TRUE
          points(x,y,col="red")
          }
      }
  }
  if (abs(y)>=5){
      y.dir<- -y.dir
  }
  Sys.sleep(0.00001)
}
```

Comment: See Greg Snow's comment here: http://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/detecting-a-key-press-td2324938.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can read key presses associated with a graphics window using `getGraphicsEvent` on some graphics devices.  The default Rstudio device does not work, but you can run `windows()` within Rstudio to create a windows graphics device which does work with `getGraphicsEvent`.

If you want something more general, then you can use the tcltk package which is cross-platform to capture the key presses and adjust your graph accordingly.  The timing functions in this package may make this the best option.

The `playSudoku` function in the sudoku package uses both methods, you could look at that code for an example.  Maybe that function is not the complete waste of time that I originally thought.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem, this is the solution I found...If you're using Window there is a freeware called AutoKeyboard available [here](https://www.murgee.com/auto-keyboard/).

You set a timer, for instance every `0.1` second the [ENTER] key gets pressed by windows and in your R code you add an `if` condition, if the user didn't actually press anything the code just goes on. Good news is you can also define a stopping key, or a time limit. 
Hope it helped.